# How do apps check for status in background?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.4

Apps like Uber check for the car's status by sending GET requests to Uber's API. I assume Facebook and E-mail apps do the same thing when checking for notifications and new e-mails. How does this work in the background? How do I keep these apps checking for the status of the car, or whether someone sent me an e-mail, or whether something is ready?  Are they using Background Fetch or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use silent remote notifications to invoke background processes. According to Apple documentation,

> When a silent notification arrives, iOS wakes up your app in the
>   background so that you can get new data from your server or do
>   background information processing. Users aren’t told about the new or
>   changed information that results from a silent notification, but they
>   can find out about it the next time they open your app.
>
> To support silent remote notifications, add the remote-notification
>   value to the UIBackgroundModes array in your Info.plist file. To learn
>   more about this array, see UIBackgroundModes.

For details https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

You can check if your application is in background mode or not and then you can call methods for background processes.

```
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground)
{
    //call your background methods.
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. Uber and Postmates and other apps have a request status checking thing for example. If I wanted to check the status of a car in an api and send a notification when the status is "arrived", they do that somehow. I want users to be notified regardless of whether the app is open.

Comment: Well when you send a notification, the user will be notified. Its up to you. A normal notification will invoke the same process and it will also notify the user. You don't have to use silent notification.

Comment: Right but this is coming from a remote push from a remote server. I don't have control over that server, I need to pull info *from* it regularly.

Comment: Actually in apps like facebook, when you have a message or any event that is relevant to you, a silent notification is sent that invokes background methods. You cannot perform a task forever in background. It must be the remote server to inform your app about the changes through notification.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess I'll have to figure out how to create my own separate remote server to continue the queries.